# Display component inline on conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple onMouseOver/onMouseLeave function that changes the state. If the state has a certain value, a component shows up. So far so good.

I use "React reveal" to make it appear smoothly.

Sadly, though the component appears correctly, it is on a different line. Yet, it should display inline since the JSX condition is directly put inside a p line:

```
<p onMouseOver={()=> this.arrow(1)} onMouseOut={()=> this.arrow(0)}> 
    <Link to="/">LEARN MORE 
    {this.props.aboutArrow === 1 ? <Fade bottom>&#x2192;</Fade> : null}
    </Link>
</p>
```

How to display the little arrow (hexcode &#x2192, inside ) in line with "Learn more"?

Comment: In your browser console, what is the DOM tree generating showing for your component `Fade`

Answer (score 0):

You could activate flex in `Link` tag by adding `display: flex` on CSS. It by default will force everything stay in the same line.

The space probably will disappear, so you can also put the entire conditional statement inside an `span` with an `margin-left` distance you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that React reveal probably renders a `<div>`, see [the source code](https://github.com/rnosov/react-reveal/blob/master/src/RevealBase.js#L439). Because `<div>` is by default displayed as block it ends up on a new line. You could change its display to inline with CSS, but it's not valid HTML to have a `<div>` inside `<a>`.